# Cannot install pyenchant on OSX

Tags: mac-osx, python

I am trying to install pyenchant on OSX snow Leopard.
I have installed enchant via macports and it produced no errors, but when I try to install pyEnchant via setup.py it gives me this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './tools/pyenchant-bdist-osx-sources/build/lib'
```

I cannot find anything on the pyenchant site og google about this error so I turn to you guys. 
What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the Portfile to see what MacPorts does to make it work.

Why can't you use the MacPorts version?

Comment: I am using the macports version.
pyEnchant is (as I understand it) python bindings for the Enchant library. I have installed Enchant just fine, but when I try to put pyEnchant on top, so I can import it in python, it just gives me the error I have posted above.